# Executing tensorflow python3 on remote server, subprocess can't interpret all of tensorflows input args. ImportError: No module named 'scripts'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, ssh, subprocess

I'm trying to execute tensorflow image identification on a remote server from my local host. My local machine has a script that runs this subprocess ssh command to execute the script on the remote server.

```
stdoutdata = subprocess.getoutput('sshpass -p \'mypassword\' ssh root@myserverIP "python3 ../var/www/html/tensorflowScreenStatus/getScreenStatus.py"')
```

I can get the script to run and return the output to my local script no problem. Inside the server side script I have a python subprocess run the same terminal command for tensorflow to screen an image, when I run it manually on the remote machine it works fine.

When the server side script is executed from my local script python doesn't know how to handle the args for tensorflow.

server side command that caused error

```
stdoutdata = subprocess.getoutput("sudo python3 -m scripts.label_image --graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --image=asdfsfsd.jpg") print("stdoutdata: " + stdoutdata)
```

Error:

```
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'scripts.label_image' (ImportError: No module named 'scripts')
```

scripts.label_image is a arg in the command that tensorflow understands what to do with. It's as if by running the tensorflow command in a subprocess, python forgets to let tensorflow read it. The same command works fine if I manually run it by sshing into the remote server.

I don't even know what to call this kind of a bug. It's as if python3 can still run but forgets what it's default args mean when run in a subprocess.

Any help at all would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that, on the remote server, you are using the same Python installation where you installed TensorFlow (especially since you are using `sudo` here) ?

Comment: I get the same result with or without sudo. I put "python3 --version" in a subprocess on the live server and executed it remotely and then manually through ssh. The Python3 version was the same. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @ElliotRobert I believe he means that you need to ensure the whole environment, not just the Python version, but packages, package managers, and even non-Python dependencies like CUDA or whatnot (especially considering the use of TensorFlow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Samuel Dion-Girardeau and nhubbard for giving it a shot. I have however found the solution. I interpreted the error as meaning python didn't know how to read the scripts.label_image directory as a path but was instead reading it as a module to import when the command was run inside a subprocess.

This was incorrect. Python didn't know how to read the scripts.label_image directory so I modified the command like so.

```
stdoutdata = subprocess.getoutput('sshpass -p \'password\' ssh root@ipaddress "python3 ../var/www/html/tensorflowScreenStatus/label_image.py --graph=../var/www/html/tensorflowScreenStatus/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --image=../var/www/html/tensorflowScreenStatus/asdfsfsd.jpg"')
```

I moved label_image.py, jpg from scripts into the parent directory, set the full directory for these folders. I also took out the middle script on the server so now my local script runs this ssh command locally, running the tensorflow command remotely, then returns the result so only one script was actually necessary.

Thanks for the attempts to help.